# Are the Carolingian and Frankish Empire the same?

Tags: franks

I'm a bit confused about Charlemagne's rule in Europe. So I saw two names that were frequent in his biography in Wikipedia: Carolingian and Frankish. And I saw that the area of those empires were very similar. So is the Carolingian and Frankish Empire the same?

Comment: Suggest you read the wiki article on the Carolingian empire.

Comment: Why is this closed?

Answer (score 9):

The Frankish Empire was ruled by two dynasties. The Merovingian (c. 5th century to 751) dynasty and Carolingian dynasty in (best known for imperial expansion under Charlemagne/Karl dem Großen) the Early Middle Ages.

- The term "Carolingian empire" refers to when the Carolingian dynasty was ruling the Frankish empire, which commonly gets traced back to Charles Martel as its founder.
- The Merovingian dynasty ruled the Frankish empire from the 5th-7th century

Comment: Summary: Carolingian = dynasty. Frankish = the frank's state. The confusion arises because this state was an empire only during the carolingian dynasty, but not during the merovingians.